# Migrate files from one cloud storage provider to another

Tags: dropbox, online-storage, cloud, mega

Is it possible to directly move files from one cloud storage provider to another, bypassing the bandwidth-intensive step of downloading the files locally and then re-uploading them?

In other words, completing a file transfer in the cloud without making it rain?

For example, [Files stored with Dropbox] --> [Files stored with Mega]

Edit: Are there any solutions apart from the dedicated, albeit pricey, services such as [cloudHQ](https://www.cloudhq.net/dropbox) and [Mover.io](https://mover.io/)?

Comment: Noted and edited. I was hopeful that something less expensive than a paid service would be able to do the job, e.g. through the storage providers' respective APIs, etc.

Comment: You can use http://www.cloudsfer.com for such a migration service.
Contact me at itay(@)Cloudsfer.com , and I'll see what free "credits" I can give you (in addition to the free 10GB)
[DISCLAIMER: I'm the R&D Manager of Tzunami/Cloudsfer]

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any coding experience?

Check out the (assuming they are made available) API's for each service and see if you can write a script to list and then store and loop through your files in one service issuing export commands with your new service as the destination.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not into programming, try [mover](https://mover.io/pricing/).

> Mover is free for personal use! You can move data and even create a scheduled backup completely for free with our Personal Connectors such as Dropbox, OneDrive, Google Drive, and more.